# How to straight out wrinkled printed receipt

Tags: packaging

I have a couple of receipts that I want to capture for business purpose, I tried to iron the back but that ink on front side just doodle onto the page which was quite amazing as of why? Is there any way I can straighten out crumbled and wrinkled receipt that been in the pocket for many weeks?

Comment: Most receipts these days are printed on thermal printers (they selectively heat the page). So yes, heat turns the receipt black.

Comment: Folding (crumpling, wrinkling, etc.) a sheet of paper breaks the fibres which cannot be un-broken. You can minimize the appearance of the damage; but, it's permanently altered. There is no "fix." You can only avoid doing it in the future by caring for what you consider valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Get a thick, heavy book. Open it to the back. Put the receipt flat on the page, and close the book. Leave it that way for 24 hours.

You can also put a weight on top of the book when it is closed. The weight can be another book, a potted plant, or anything heavy.

Comment: the ink "doodled" because the receipt was printed on *thermal paper* which contains ink encapsulated in wax. the heat melted all the wax and released all the ink.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Did you mean to put this comment on my answer, or on the original question? My answer doesn't mention the doodling, but the original question does.

Comment: no, i meant to put it on the OP's question, sorry if i did it wrong. -NN

Comment: @nielsnielsen I think you should copy the comment onto the original question too! Other readers will want to know about thermal paper, and they may not read the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother straightening it out beforehand. Put the receipt on the glass plate of the copier, and place a book on top of it.

Comment: Although it's probably safe to assume the OP will be copying the receipt, there's no mention of copying in the question. So for others reading this question (which I upvoted), put the receipt on the glass place of a copier, place a book on top of it, and then make a copy of it or scan it into a digital file.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny bit of moisture helps the paper straightening up. Wet a dishcloth or paper towel, then wring it out thoroughly and wipe it over the receipt. The paper is supposed to become slightly damp, not to soak and rip!

Then straighten out the damp receipt and let it dry. Putting it between 2 sheets of dry paper towel and weightening it down can help to get it nice and wrinkle-free.

Answer (score 0):

the ink "doodled" because the receipt was printed on thermal paper which contains ink encapsulated in wax. the heat melted all the wax and released all the ink.

This means you cannot use a heated iron to flatten a piece of thermal printout. you must squeeze the wrinkled paper between two flat objects.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't answer the question of how to correct it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16496)

Comment: I did so at the suggestion of another reader. will edit.